# Devise routing error when i put the before_action :authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a list of sessions(not devise sessions, is cinema sessions) and i have a link to new offer of this session offer is a nested resource from user. To Buy(create offer) the user must be logged (because the reference of the user is required to create a offer). when i put  before_action :authenticate_user! in the session_controller(again cinema session not the devise session) i getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new
 Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000034bc708>
```

here is my routes.rb:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tickets
  resources :offers
  resources :prices
  resources :movies
  devise_for :sessions, controllers: {
   new: 'session/new'
  }
  resources :sessions do
    resources :offers
  end
  resources :rooms
  resources :seats
  resources :cinemas
    get 'welcome/index'
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
     registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  root 'welcome#index'
 end
```

here is my session_controller(cinema session, not devise):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html
  ...
```

new.html.erb (session_controller):

```
 <h1>New session</h1>
 <%= render 'form' %>
 <%= link_to 'Back', sessions_path %>
```

_form.erb (session):

```
<%= form_for(@session) do |f| %>
  <% if @session.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@session.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this session from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @session.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cinema_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :cinema_id, Cinema.all, :id, :nameCine %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :room_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :room_id, Room.all, :id, :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :movie_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :movie_id, Movie.all, :id, :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bgn_date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :bgn_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :end_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The problem in your view (not in router). Look at error message.

Comment: yeah, but without the before_action :authenticate_user! everthing works fine

Comment: Show your `new.html.erb` file.

Comment: edit: added new.html.erb

Comment: It doesn't have line #10 where error has been raised.

Answer (score 0):

This is newbie mistake, i was looking for anything in devise registration problem. But the error is on the view of (devise)session/new where i have automatically generated field for the name, but to login this is not used, only email and pass fields.
I removed the name field from (devise)session/new everthing works like a charm.